# Fast way to convert a binary number to a decimal number

Tags: c++, binary

I have to convert a binary number like for example `unsigned int bin_number = 10101010` into its decimal representation (i.e. `170`) as quickly as possible? What is the best algorithm?

Comment: Does `10101010` come from the user of your program, or is it just a literal in code?

Comment: Can you give a better picture of where the binary number originates from? Is it known at compile time or only run-time? Is it stored in a string or some other structure? Knowing this will make answering the question much easier.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. Usually i get the number run-time, but sometimes at compile-time. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using templates you can solve this problem at *compile-time*.

```
template<unsigned long num>
struct binary
{
    static unsigned const value =
        binary<num/10>::value << 1 | num % 10;
};

// Specialization for zero
template<>
struct binary<0>
{ static unsigned const value = 0; };
```

The binary template is instantiated again with a smaller `num`, until `num` reaches zero and the specialization is used as a termination condition.

Example: `std::cout << binary<10101010>::value;`

For *run-time* problem:

```
unsigned binary_to_decimal(unsigned num)
{
    unsigned res = 0;

    for(int i = 0; num > 0; ++i)
    {
        if((num % 10) == 1)
            res += (1 << i);

        num /= 10;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Using templates you can compute anything at compile time, since they are turing complete. Does that however help the OP to get anything done?

Comment: -1:  I doubt it.  If OP had an ICE, which he'd need in order to use metaprogramming, he could just do `const double d = 170.0;`  As it is he is sureley getting the inbound number at run-time, so metaprogramming is out.

Comment: Actually, I think this is rather clever - and more to the point it does work. True, it will not work on numbers only known at runtime and true, it's far more likely that the OP wants that *but* he hasn't specified that.

Comment: @gliderkite:  Yep. :) The elaboration on the metaprogramming is educational to those that don't know about it, if not likely to be applicable to the actual problem.  More importantly you have provided what is probably a solution to the actual problem.  Though I don't know if it's the fastest possible algorithm, it's surely fast enough, and OP didn't specify what "best" means anyway.  I've removed my downvote and given you +1.

Comment: At compile time you don't need template, you can juste writte `int i = 0b10101010;` it's standard : http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#nt:binary-literal

Answer (score 11):

Well, if this "number" is actually a string gotten from some source (read from a file or from a user) that you converted into a number (thinking it to be more appropriate for an actual number), which is quite likely, you can use a `std::bitset` to do the conversion:

```
#include <bitset>

unsigned int number = std::bitset<32>("10101010").to_ulong();
```

(Of course the `32` here is implementation-defined and might be more appropriately written as `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits`.)

But if it is really a number (integer variable) in the (very) first place you could do:

```
#include <string>

unsigned int number = std::bitset<32>(std::to_string(bin_number)).to_ulong();
```

(using C++11's `to_string`) But this will probably not be the most efficient way anymore, as others have presented more efficient algorithms based on numbers. But as said, I doubt that you really get this number as an actual integer variable in the very first place, but rather read it from some text file or from the user.

Comment: Thanks, this a good answer, but the number is not a string, i cannot use C++11 and i asked for a fast solution!

Comment: @Nick So may I ask where you got it from, you obviously have to get it from somewhere and I doubt you actually read a binary number, that represents a number just containing 0s and 1s, that would be rubbish. It really only makes sense to get such a number from some textual medium in the first place. The only exception is when you need binary constants, but for this you can just use another method (gliderkite's template program is very nice). But for most cases when it comes as a string, the bitset solution shouldn't be the slowest one (and it doesn't need C++11, either).

Answer (score 4):

Actually if you write `unsigned int bin_number = 10101010`, this is interpreted as a decimal number by the compiler.

If you want to write a binary literal in your source code, you should use [`BOOST_BINARY`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY). Then, you just need to print it using `cout`, decimal is the default...

```
unsigned int i = BOOST_BINARY(10101010);
std::cout << i; // This prints 170
```

Comment: Some compilers also support the "0b" prefix (`i = 0b10101010`), but with boost you ensure portability.

Comment: @Nick  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY

Comment: I believe it to be a macro that processes your binary litteral during preprocessing. I did not actually look at the internals. Here is the documentation for this specific macro: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY

Comment: @Nick check this video
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-5-of-n

Comment: Not if used right, and I completely trust the boost libraries (seriously, you should take a look if you never used them!)

Comment: @Aurel tanks i'll do, but macro is really [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.5) even for Bjarne Stroustrup!

Comment: @Nick Yes and no.  In this case, the necessary precautions have been taken: a prefix to avoid name conflicts, and all in caps, so you know that it is a macro, and can take appropriate precautions.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 (even if C++11 is more limited than C++14 in that regard), function can be `constexpr` so avoid necessity of `template` to have compile time value.

Here a version C++14 compatible:

```
constexpr unsigned binary_to_decimal(unsigned num)
{
    unsigned res = 0;

    while (num)
    {
        res = 10 * res + num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And for literals, you can even use binary literals since C++14:

```
0b1010'1010 // or 0b10101010 without separator
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of binary digits that you're dealing with *and* it's always fixed *and* the binary number comes in a string (as it would if read from a file or stdin) at runtime (i.e. compile time conversion not possible) then you could adopt this approach:

```
int to_binary( const char* c )
{
    return ( ( c[0] & 1 ) ? 0x80 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[1] & 1 ) ? 0x40 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[2] & 1 ) ? 0x20 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[3] & 1 ) ? 0x10 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[4] & 1 ) ? 0x08 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[5] & 1 ) ? 0x04 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[6] & 1 ) ? 0x02 : 0x00 ) |
           ( ( c[7] & 1 ) ? 0x01 : 0x00 );
}
```

This assumes an fixed eight digit binary number. called like this:

```
std::cout << to_binary("10101010") << std::endl;
```

If you had a sixteen bit number you could still use it:

```
const char* bin_number = "1010101010101010";

// Deal with 16 bits
std::cout << ( to_binary( bin_number ) << 8 | to_binary( bin_number + 8 ) ) << std::endl;
```

Note that there is clearly no bounds checking here and I'm relying on the fact that the LSB of '1' is always 1 and '0' is always 0 (so not validating that it's actually a binary input.)

Naturally, it's pretty specific and not very flexible, but it does the job and I'm not sure that you'd get much faster.