# C++ A method that returns the decimal value as an integer of a binary that is represented with a boolean array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

The boolean array has true for 1 and false for 0.
8 would be represented as false false false true, where true is at index 3. 6 would be false, true, true. Also I want to do this without using pow(). The method will return the decimal representation as an integer.

What I have so far:

```
int Binary::binaryToInteger(bool *binaryArray, int size)
{
    Something that will keep track of the index and something that will keep track of
    the amount I need to multiply by added to a total and an if else that will take care
    of true or false

    return total;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast way to convert a binary number to a decimal number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949491/fast-way-to-convert-a-binary-number-to-a-decimal-number)

Comment: Is there any representation of the signed-ness of the number in the input array?

Comment: @MarkB: The sign of an `int` is in its highest bit. So if the array size is `<= numeric_limits<int>::digits`, the array represents an unsigned number.  If the size of the array is `== numeric_limits<int>::digits+1`, the last array element specifies the sign. `numeric_limits<int>::digits` does not count the sign bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do this without using `pow()`

Using `pow()` for powers of two is an overkill, at least on binary hardware. You can use

```
int mask = 1 << bitNumber;
```

to produce an `int` with all bits set to zero except `bitNumber`, which would be set to one.

> something that will keep track of the amount I need to multiply by added to a total

There is no need for multiplication. As for the addition, you can replace it with bitwise "OR":

```
res |= 1 << bitNumber;
```

If you go through your array of `bool` values, set `res` to zero initially, and apply the above operation to `bitNumber` indexes where `binaryArray[bitNumber]` is set to `true`, then the final value of `res` would correspond to an `int` defined by your array of `bool` values.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into what a bitwize "OR" is.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mul = 1;
int accum = ;
for(int i = size - 1; i > 0; i++) {
    accum+=mul*binaryArray[i];
    mul*=2;
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: @Bapho Yeah, I wrote that really quick.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept> 

int Binary::binaryToInteger(bool *binaryArray, int size)
{
    if ((size < 0) || (size > (std::numeric_limits<int>::digits+1))) // +1 for sign bit, which digits ignores
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid size!");

    // The boolean array has true for 1 and false for 0.
    // 8 would be represented as "false false false true", where true is at index 3.
    // 6 would be "false, true, true".

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (binaryArray[i])
            result |= (1 << i);
    }

    return result;
}
```